# Grab value after last slash in RegEx and ignore category slugs

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, slug

I've URLs setup in following formats on old site:

```
blog/cat1/my-post-title
blog/my-post-title
blog/my-post-title/
blog/cat1/sub-cat1/my-post-title
```

and I'm trying to setup RegEx redirect for the following format:

```
articles/my-post-title
```

The category slugs are no longer required

So far, my poor attempt has been following, which you can see is flawed:

Rule 1:

```
blog\/(#?.*)\/(#?.*)\/(#?.*)

articles/$3
```

Rule 2:

```
blog\/(#?.*)\/(#?.*)

articles/$2
```

Rule 3:

```
blog\/(#?.*)

articles/$1
```

Can we setup a single rule and grab just the post slug that comes after the last slash and ignore all category slugs, if available?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working with the following:

```
([^/]+\/?[blog/]{2}?\/)(.*?)([^/]+)/$
```

And to get the post slug:

```
articles/$3
```

Comment: The above works if you have / at the end of your URL, for URLs without / at the end, use following 

`([^/]+\/?[blog/]{2}?\/)(.*?)([^/]+)$`